# Is $f$ homotopic to $g?$ Yes/ No

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

let $S^1$ be the  unit circle  of  complex plane  and let $f, g:S^1 \to S^1$  the  map $f(z)=z$ and  $g(z)=z^2$

Is  $f$ homotopic to $g?$

**My attempt** : Yes, I think

Take the  map  $F : S^1 \times [0,1] \to S^1$ defined by  $F(e^{i\theta},t)=e^{i(\theta + t\pi) }$

Also,  $F$ is  continious  because  it is the  compoisition of map

$S^1 \times I \to S^1 \times S^1  \to S^1 \to S^1$

Comment: But your $F$ is not a homotopy between $f$ and $g$

Comment: Do you know what these maps do to the fundamental group?

Comment: Sorry , I don't  know @SteveD I'm new to Algebraic topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $F$ is a homotopy between $f$ and $h(z):=-iz$.  Since $h$ is just a rotation of $f$ by $\pi$, they are clearly homotopic.

You may need some firepower to do this.   For instance you can define the notion of degree,  and show that it's a homotopy invariant.   Since $f$ has degree $1$, $g$ degree $2$, they are not homotopic.

I believe that the name Heinz Hopf comes up here, around the beginning of the $20$th century.